# FilePermissionError when installing nokogiri (1.7.0.1)

Tags: rubygems, nokogiri

I have already gotten Jekyll and my OS is Windows.
When I entered `sudo bundle install` I got the following error:

> An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.7.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue
>   Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.7.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.

I then followed the instructions written in the error message and got a permissions error:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>       You don't have write permissions into the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory.

People had similar problems in the past, but none of the solutions provided worked for me.

Comment: You need to do the sudo part for that one as well (sudo gem install...). It's not going to work though because you're missing some library - likely suspects are `sudo apt install build-essential ruby-dev libxml2`

Comment: @pguardiario I did what you recommended.....however, now I got another problem. When I do **sudo gem install nokogiri - '1.7.0.1'**, I get the Error **ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '1.7.0.1' (>= 0) in any repository** Thank You for the help!

Comment: that should be `-v`

Comment: @pguardiario I added the **-v** but got this error **ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.**

Comment: It means there's another missing library. You'e going to have to google the errors for fixes until they go away.